# How do I authenticate to Azure Storage from Java using MSI?

Tags: java, azure, blob, storage

I can't figure out how to create a BlobClient, or a StorageAccount reference using a Managed Identity (MI/MSI) in Java. Creating and using the MI to asign RBAC on the storage is straightforward, but I can't work out how to make use of this in my code.

I got this working previously with KeyVault, because I found a lot more examples online of other people doing this, and it was ultimately really simple:

```java
MSICredentials credentials = new MSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
KeyVaultClient kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
```

But I can't find a similar Storage class that will take the MSICredentials as parameter, nor find a way to create StorageCredentials using the MSICredentials.

Has anyone else got this working or have any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way for Azure Storage Account to authenticate from MSI in Java. Just in a different way from KeyVault.

It also shows in the document [Azure AD Authentication for Azure Blobs and Queues now in public preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-aad-authentication-for-storage/). There are three ways to authenticate for Azure Storage, see [Credential in Azure Storage Java V10 Overview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/wiki/Azure-Storage-Java-V10-Overview#credentials).

You should first get the access token with the MSI and then use TokenCredentials to authenticate. See the way that [Getting a token for system assigned identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/authorization/msi-auth-token-provider-jar#getting-a-token-for-system-assigned-identity).

Comment: Thanks for the info, and sorry for the slow response, I get very limited time to look at this unfortunately. I think that last link, for the msi-auth-token-provider-jar, looks interesting but I couldn't access the jar to try it. I tried using the OAuth approach previously and whilst it worked with curl, I couldn't get it working in code. I will probably park this for now and focus on ServicePrincipal access instead and maybe revisit the MI approach when it's a bit more mature.

Comment: Hi, sorry, to be clear I did try it but I was unable to get it working, so I can't validate this as a solution. Probably my fault, but unless I get more time to look at it I won't know.